# Is there a better way to remove characters from an integer in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, int

I need to check if an integer has 6 characters, and if it does, remove the first three characters and return the resultant integer.  Otherwise, just return the original integer.  This is what i have, I would like to know if there is a better/faster/more efficient way in C#?

```
public static int MyMethod(int originalInt)
    {
        int outputInt = originalInt;

        string temp = originalInt.ToString();

        if (temp.Length == 6)
        {
            temp = temp.Substring(3);
            if (!Int32.TryParse(temp, out outputInt))
            {
                outputInt = originalInt;
            }
        }

        return outputInt;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off thinking about this mathematically?  An integer with 6 digits is between 100000 and 999999 inclusive or -99999 and -10000.  To "remove" digits you use the % operator.

Comment: You can do the first part by checking the value of the number (>= 1000000 and <= 999999). You can do the second part with integer division, no need for strings.

Comment: do you want the first 3 characters as the new integer, or the remaining characters? If you have "123456", do you want "123", or "456"?

Comment: i want "456" as the new integer

Comment: yes we can assume only positive integers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why use strings at all?

```
if (originalInt >= 100000 && originalInt < 1000000)
    return originalInt % 1000;
return originalInt;
```

(Assuming `originalInt` is always positive)

Comment: why you need the if, why not just % 1000000 ??

Comment: Because otherwise it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @YuliamChandra - because, apparently, if the number isn't between 100000 and 999999 we should "return the original integer". And if it is between those numbers we should "remove the first 3 characters" - if you can explain how `%1000000` would achieve *either* of those, I'll be impressed.

Comment: Don't forget negative numbers.  Does the - count as a digit?

Comment: @plinth - that's why I've said my answer assumes positive numbers. If negatives are allowed, we need a clearer spec on what the rules are.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I believe you have an extra `0` in the first comparison; the way it's written, it will never be satisfied.

Comment: @decPL - corrected. I was sure I'd counted right, but somehow ended up with the extra digit.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
public static int MyMethod(int originalInt)
    {
    return (originalInt > 99999 && originalInt <1000000)?originalInt % 1000 :  originalInt;
    }
```

It returns the result that you need